# How can i make the attack state of my FSM work?/ Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, unityscript

Hey guys please check my fsm here my attack state doesn’t seem to work and idk why. If anyone knows please please help thank you.This script is quite long so please bare with me and thank you, If you see stuff you think i can do to improve my work please tell me so i know for the future cause i'm currently only intermediate lvl eish still lots to learn.

```
public class PlagueFiniteStateMachine : MonoBehaviour
{        
    public enum doctorState
    {
        // define every state needed
        Walking,
        Attack,
        Charge,
        Return,
        Idle,
        Follow,
    }

    [SerializeField] float visibleDis= 15f;
    [SerializeField] float visibleAngle= 10f;
    [SerializeField] int attack= 10;
    [SerializeField] float distance = 5f;

    private Animator ani;
    public LayerMask ignore;

    [SerializeField] private GameObject player;
    [SerializeField] NavMeshAgent plague;
    [SerializeField] GameObject targetPos;
    [SerializeField] GameObject aiBase;
    [SerializeField] GameObject vaccine;

    [SerializeField]GameObject Indicator;
    PlayerMovement op;

    //[SerializeField]Vector3 destination;

    doctorState currentState;
    
    void Start()
    {
        Indicator.SetActive(false);

        plague = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        ani = this.GetComponent<Animator>();
        op = GetComponent<PlayerMovement>();

        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");

        targetPos = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Flag");
        aiBase = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("AIBase");
        vaccine = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Flag");

        ChangeState(doctorState.Walking); // on entry walking state is default state
        plague.SetDestination(targetPos.transform.position);
    }
   
    void Update()
    {
        float stillAttack = Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, plague.transform.position);

        StateHandler();
        if (stillAttack <= distance)
        {
            ChangeState(doctorState.Attack);

            plague.SetDestination(player.transform.position);
            op.takeDamage(attack);
        }
    }

    // method to handle behaviours between states & conditions to switch states 
    void StateHandler()
    {
        switch (currentState)
        {
          case doctorState.Walking:
                if (CanSeePlayer())
                {
                    ChangeState(doctorState.Charge);
                }
                else if (CanAttack())
                {
                    ChangeState(doctorState.Attack);
                }
                else if (ReachedTarget())
                {
                    ChangeState(doctorState.Return);
                }
                break;

            case doctorState.Attack:
                if(CanSeePlayer())
                {
                    ChangeState(doctorState.Charge);
                }
                else if (!CanAttack())
                {
                    ChangeState(doctorState.Walking);
                }
                else if(ReachedTarget())
                {
                    ChangeState(doctorState.Return);
                }                
                break;
            
               case doctorState.Charge:
                if (!CanSeePlayer())
                {
                    ChangeState(doctorState.Walking);
                }
                else if(CanAttack())
                {
                    ChangeState(doctorState.Attack);
                }
                else if (ReachedTarget())
                {
                    ChangeState(doctorState.Return);
                }
                break;

                case doctorState.Return:
                if (AgentReturnedVaccine()) 
                {
                    Debug.Log("Agent secured the package, We have failed.");
                    ChangeState(doctorState.Idle);
                }
                break;      
        }                     
    }

    // method to handle the behaviour in transition between states
    void ChangeState(doctorState newState)
    { 
        if(currentState== newState) return; // to prevent unnecessary transitions;

        currentState= newState;

        //here is the enter logic for current states

        switch (currentState)
        {
            case doctorState.Walking:
                OnEnterWalking();
                break;

              case doctorState.Charge:
                OnEnterCharge();
                break;

               case doctorState.Attack:
                OnEnterAttack();
                break;

                case doctorState.Idle:
                  OnEnterIdle();
                  return;

                 case doctorState.Return:
                  OnEnterReturn();
                  break;
        }           
    }

    // Enter and exit methods for each state
    void OnEnterWalking()
    {
        ani.SetBool("CanAttack", false);
        ani.SetBool("CanCharge", false);
        ani.SetBool("IsWalking", true);
       
        plague.SetDestination(targetPos.transform.position);
       
        Debug.Log("Current state is:  " + currentState);
    }
    
    void OnEnterIdle()
    {
        Indicator.SetActive(false);

        ani.SetBool("CanAttack", false);
        ani.SetBool("CanCharge", false);
        ani.SetBool("IsWalking", false);
        ani.SetBool("IsIdle", true);           

        Debug.Log("Current state is:  " + currentState);
    }

    void OnEnterCharge()
    {
        Indicator.SetActive(false);

        ani.SetBool("IsWalking", false);
        ani.SetBool("CanAttack", false);
        ani.SetBool("CanCharge", true);
       
        plague.SetDestination(player.transform.position);

        Debug.Log("Current state is:  " + currentState);
    }

    void OnEnterAttack()
    {
        Indicator.SetActive(false);
       // float stillAttack = Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, plague.transform.position);

        ani.SetBool("CanCharge", false);
        ani.SetBool("IsWalking", false);
        ani.SetBool("CanAttack", true);
        /*
        if(stillAttack<= distance)
        {
            plague.SetDestination(player.transform.position);
            op.takeDamage(attack);
        }
       */

        Debug.Log("Current state is:  " + currentState);
    }

    void OnEnterReturn()
    {
        Indicator.SetActive(true);

        ani.SetBool("IsWalking", false);
        ani.SetBool("CanAttack", false);
        ani.SetBool("CanCharge", true);

        plague.SetDestination(aiBase.transform.position);
        Debug.Log("Current state is:  " + currentState);
    }

    bool Captured(Collider other)
    {
        string thisTag = "Agent";
        GameObject someObject = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag(thisTag);
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "flag" && someObject != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public bool CanSeePlayer() // boolean method to check if player is in range
    {
       Vector3 direction=  player.transform.position- this.transform.position;
         float angle= Vector3.Angle(direction, this.transform.forward);

        if(direction.magnitude< visibleDis && angle< visibleAngle)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public bool CanAttack()
    {
        /*
         RaycastHit hit;
         int maxDis = 5;
        ;

         if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.forward, maxDis,  ignore ))
         {
             Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, transform.forward, Color.red);
             Debug.Log("Hit " + player);
             return true;
         }
         return false;
        */
        if(Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position,plague.transform.position) <= distance)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool ReachedTarget()
    {
        if(Vector3.Distance(targetPos.transform.position, plague.transform.position) < distance)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
   
    bool AgentReturnedVaccine()
    {
        return Vector3.Distance(aiBase.transform.position, plague.transform.position) < distance;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (Captured(other))
        {
            Debug.Log("Returning to base");
            ChangeState(doctorState.Return);
        }
    }      
}
```

I tried adding my attack logic to the update function for it to constantly check if the player is in the appropriate distance to attack but no victory.

You see the agent is supposed to attack the player when in range, with a specified animation set to it, but it doesn't attack the player.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn’t seem to work"? What exactly is the problem? You can try adding more logging on the CanAttack, CanSeePlayer, etc to see exactly what are the distances and the angle. Another suggestion is to implement the FSM pattern in which you have an abstract State class and inherit each state as a different class, instead of the enum switch.

Comment: oh im sorry i forgot to say the issue, apologies. You see the agent is supposed to attack the player when in range, with a specified animation set to it, but it doesn't attack the player. Does that make sense? i read about the state pattern but i don't think im ready for it yet cause there's a lot i don't understand but when i complete this i am going to implement the fsm pattern

Comment: It is very difficult to tell why it won't attack. There is a lot of "hidden" code, such as parameters that control the Animations which we don't know what they do or how they work. Furthermore, there is a conflict as you have dedicated states that check for attacks, but you overwrite it in `Update()` with a separate range validation (for example this means it will attack even if vaccinated since you do a force attack state switch in `Update()`. We also don't know what `PlayerMovement.takeDamage()` does and whether that has any impact in your issue.

Comment: FSMs are in general easier to debug visually then other issues. In this case, you'll need some UI objects that are only used in your editor or dev build, such as UI TMP text objects that display the current state and all the parameters (such as the distances which are the most important factors in your code) + angle. If we look at the code like this without even knowing the positioning of the objects on the map, yes, the code *should* work. Why it doesn't? It can be a handful of reasons such as race conditions in states fighting eachother on which should be the current state.

Comment: As for improvements, most of what I'd say is trivial, such as don't abuse `this.whatever`, have proper variable and function name patterns (what is `ani`? yes, I know what it is, you know what it is, but would others? What is `visibleDis`? Would you agree `visibleDist` is better or `visibleDistance`? Not for now, but for 4 years from now when you read the code. Others would prolly be some allignment and to not put "," after the last enumerator. Last but not least, agree on coding conventions between Pascal and CamelCase, but not only. You combine a lot of them. Coding standards matter a lot.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).